# Difference between forward and backslash

Tags: filesystems, pathname

What is the difference in using a forward slash and backslash in navigating file systems. Also what is the difference between `./` and `../`?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/

Comment: Did you try googling for the question title?  This is trivial to find an answer to on the internet currently.

Comment: Excellent answer wrt. MS/Windows on dupe question:http://stackoverflow.com/a/38428899/321013

Comment: Question asked 4 years ago cannot be a duplicate of one asked yesterday. Sorry! Try Again?

Comment: @nocomprende Which question is marked "duplicate" is usually determined by which question has better answers.

Comment: @MosheKatz so, merge them? One question, best answers. Done.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, in most languages backslashes need to be escaped in string literals, slashes do not. Further backslashes only work on Windows, while slashes work pretty much everywhere.

On the other hand, when passing path names as arguments to Windows programs, using slashes might not work because many Windows programs use slashes to signify command line flags, so you need to use backslashes.

On `.` vs. `..`: `.` is the current directory, `..` is the parent directory.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft operating systems (e.g. DOS and Windows) use backslashes (\), UNIX-based operating systems (e.g. Linux) use slashes (/).

The dot (.) means the current working directory, it's like saying "here". The double dot (..) means the parent directory.

Comment: just a sidenote: modern windows boxes also support the "/", i.e: cd /

Comment: You can use slashes in Windows path names as well (most of the time anyway).

Answer (score 1):

The difference between slash and backslash in Windows are from my tests at least non-existing, but I believe that in earlier editions they used backslash. UNIX systems uses slash.

The difference between `./` and `../` is that `./` represents the position in the hierarchy where you are standing while `../` is the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is used for:

File names in DOS and Windows, e.g. D:\documents\office, C:\java\jdk
escape sequences in C, Unix, and other languages/systems that borrow the same syntax (C++, Java, etc.). For example, \n means newline and \t means tab.

Forward slash is used for:

- File names on Unix (and Mac OS X, since it is derived from Unix), e.g.  `/cs/student/jsmith/cs8/lab00`, `/Users/Shared/cs8/cTurtle.py`.
- Web addresses (URLs), such as `http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs8`.
- Dividing in many programming languages, e.g. battingAvg = hits / atBats;