# Flask download file not working

Tags: flask

I am try download file from my flask application.

My method

```
@admin.route('/download_doc', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download_doc():
    doc_id = request.json['id']
    doc = Doc.query.filter(Doc.id==doc_id).first()
    filename = doc.filename
    uploads = os.path.join(app.root_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    return send_from_directory(directory=uploads, filename=filename)
```

Error 404. Why?

[image]

When I try print uploads variable. I see, not valid path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Paths with slashes and backslashes are ok for Windows. Check this question: [Difference between forward slash (/) and backslash (\) in file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428561/difference-between-forward-slash-and-backslash-in-file-path)

However, what's weird on your screenshot is that you have two `/app` folders in your path and this can be an issue. Try to return files in this way:

```
return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Also, check [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_from_directory) for `send_from_directory` method and hint about `Sending files and Performance`.

Comment: No, my app structure only one folder app. UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'app/static/doc', app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER.

Comment: Yes, but you're joining your `upload` folder with `root` folder, so you're getting two `/app` items in a result (as on your screenshot).

Comment: not work do like this return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename, as_attachment=True)

Comment: Your `UPLOAD_FOLDER` should be `'static/doc'`.

Comment: After change show valid path, but not download file. Maybe permission problem?

Comment: It can be permission problem or file doesn't exist. Maybe you've missed file extension?