# How to find a filepath in a list of strings in Windows regardless of direction of slashes in strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Windows, using Python 2.7, the contents of a file are read and certain lines from that file are (after being prepended with a string "D:\abcddev\") put into a list called FilePathList.
These lines are paths to files, for example:

```
D:\abcddev\toeblog/folderX/fileA.h
D:\abcddev\toeblog/folderY/fileB.h
```

You will notice that the paths contain a mixture of forward and backward slashes. There is unfortunately nothing I can do about that, that's how they are created and I only have access to them after that.

I want to check if a certain path is found in the list. The path contains all backward slashes.

So, continuing the present example, I want to check if the following is in the list above:

```
D:\abcddev\toeblog\folderY\fileB.h
```

As you can see, this string contains all backward slashes.

So my problem is how to check for equality regardless of whether the slash is a forward or backward slash.

My idea was to convert all the members of the FilePathList to backward slash separated paths and put these into a new list NormalizedFilePathList, and then to search that list for the path I wish to find.

So this is my code:

```
# Declare list
NormalizedFilePathList = []

# Add backward slash separated lines to NormalizedFilePathList
for file in FilePathList:
    NormalizedFilePathList.append (os.path.normpath(file)) 

# Display the contents of NormalizedFilePathList
for file in NormalizedFilePathList
    print file

# Create the string to be searched for
test_file = 'D:\abcddev\toeblog\folderY\fileB.h'

# Search for the string in NormalizedPathFileList
if test_file in NormalizedFilePathList:
    print "Found test_file"
else:
    print "Did not find test_file"
```

Here is the output of the above:

```
D:\abcddev\toeblog\folderX\fileA.h
D:\abcddev\toeblog\folderY\fileB.h
Did not find test_file
```

Why does this not work? There is obviously a match for 'D:\abcddev\toeblog\folderY\fileB.h'.

I tried a few things in my perplexity to clarify matters, as follows:

1. Printed out the strings in the NormalizedPathFileList using repr() to see if there were any hidden characters preventing a match being found. No, there were not.
2. Created artificially a new list that I populated manually and searched that instead.

```
ManualList = ['D:\abcddev\toeblog\folderX\fileA.h','D:\abcddev\toeblog\folderY\fileB.h']

for file in ManualList
    print file

# Search for the string in ManualList
if test_file in ManualList:
    print "Found test_file"
else:
    print "Did not find test_file"
```

Here was the output:

```
D:\abcddev    oeblog\folderX\fileA.h
D:\abcddev    oeblog\folderY\fileB.h
Found test_file
```

As you can seem there is a tab character in the middle of the line. 
That is because the string contains '\t'

If I print out the test_file, for the same reason, I also see:

```
D:\abcddev    oeblog\folderY\fileB.h
```

This explains why the search works when I create a string manually.

So the question is how to escape the \t character in the test_file string ?

Note that whatever code I write must also work in Linux.

Comment: What is `FilePathList`?

Comment: Could you post the output of `print NormalizedFilePathList` of your first case?

Comment: First of all, upgrade your Python version - it's dead (and if it's a school computer or something, tell those people to upgrade it) :)

Comment: FilePathList is a list containing strings. Each string is a full path to a file (with a mix of backward, forward slashes). It is mentioned in the example above:

Comment: Torxed. The version of Python used in out of my hands. I have to work this what I have got.

Comment: Phineas: the output is printed already: it is ```D:\abcddev\joeblog\folderX\fileA.h
D:\abcddev\joeblog\folderY\fileB.h```

Comment: Low chance that it will work, but try replace ('/','\') instead of os.path.... . Please let us know what happend, in the comments

Comment: I would also try next replacing all \ with / or \\

Comment: I tried replaced '/' with '\' and also '\' with '\\' in the list, but it did not work. However, I noticed believe that the issue is the inclusion of a '\t' in my search string, which causes a tab character to be introduced in it, with the result that it does not find it in my list. In my post above, the path is one I invented for this posting. However, in actual fact it contains a \t character. I will adjust my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into issues because backslashes indicate [escape characters](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). E.g. `\t` is a tab, as you discovered, but Python will treat `\a` and `\f` as escape characters as well. It turns out they stand for ASCII bell and form feed, respectively. Who knew? One solution is to use raw strings, indicated with an `r` before the quote marks of a string, which will not check for escape characters and will treat backslashes as plain text. Otherwise you need to write `\\` to display a backslash.

Also, `os.path.normpath` [only changes forward slashes to backslashes on Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) and will not do what you need in Linux, so you will need a `replace` as well. In general, if you have to pick all forward slashes or all backslashes, go with all forward, because [Windows can handle forward slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428561/difference-between-forward-slash-and-backslash-in-file-path/38428899) while other OSes can't handle backslashes.

```
# Declare list    
ManualList = [r'D:\abcddev\toeblog/folderX/fileA.h',r'D:\abcddev\toeblog/folderY/fileB.h']
NormalizedFilePathList = []

# Add standardized slash separated lines to NormalizedFilePathList
for file in ManualList:
    NormalizedFilePathList.append (os.path.normpath(file.replace('\\', '/')))

# Display the contents of NormalizedFilePathList
for file in NormalizedFilePathList:
    print file

# Create the string to be searched for. 
# Use forward slashes in the string below to preserve compatibility for Linux. 
# normpath will convert them to backslashes on Windows.
test_file = os.path.normpath('D:/abcddev/toeblog/folderY/fileB.h')

# Search for the string in NormalizedPathFileList
if test_file in NormalizedFilePathList:
    print "Found test_file"
else:
    print "Did not find test_file"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the slashes and compare?

```
def strip_slashes(path):
  return path.replace('/','').replace('\\','')

paths = ['D:\\p1\\p2/folderY/fileB.h','D:\\p1\\p2/folderX/fileA.h']
stripped_paths = [strip_slashes(p) for p in paths]
path_to_find_1 = 'D:\\p1\p2\\folderY\\fileB.h'
stripped_path_to_find_1 = strip_slashes(path_to_find_1)
path_to_find_2 = 'D:\\p1\p452\\folderY\\fileB.h'
stripped_path_to_find_2 = strip_slashes(path_to_find_2)


print('----------------')

print(stripped_path_to_find_1 in stripped_paths)
print(stripped_path_to_find_2 in stripped_paths)
```

Comment: That's another possibility. Thanks for the suggestion.