# What is the difference between "\" and "/" used in file path in a java program?

Tags: java, file-handling

I wanted to know the difference between "\" and "/" used in file path in a java program and also the difference between "\" and "\" used in file path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between forward slash (/) and backslash (\‌) in file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428561/difference-between-forward-slash-and-backslash-in-file-path)

Comment: Nothing. Java translated ``\`` to `/` on platforms where that is necessary (and vice-versa where ``\`` is required). I suggest using `/` because it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

/ is a linux and mac os based delimiter for traversing directories and files.
\ is Windows based .

Comment: Incorrect, even in windows java allows one to use `/` and not `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is using on Linux OS or Window OS. In a Java program, you can use the file path in both two ways:

```
String s = "C:\\Users\\DEU1HC\\Desktop\\IntelliJ 2019.3.1\\bin";
```

or

```
String s = "C:/Users/DEU1HC/Desktop/IntelliJ 2019.3.1/bin";
```

Answer (score -1):

In the narrow scope of File IO, char `\` is only thing that is allowed in path. Even in non-linux OS `\` is used as path separator.