# load RData file shows this error: embedded nul character

Tags: r, character, load, nul, rdata

I tried to figure out the problem, but didn't find a solution.

Following problem:
I've tried to load this Rdata file. It is about 4 GB. But I always got the error.

```
Error in load.....Embedded nul character.

load("C:/Users/setup/Desktop/WZ/data/rd2_full.RData")
```

How can I handle this problem. Is there a possibility to ignore the nul character?

It would be nice to hear from some of you.

Comment: Read this and edit your question. Chances of an awnser are much higher: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try to reverse the / to \

`load("C:\Users\setup\Desktop\WZ\data\rd2_full.RData")`

See here for more info:
[Difference between forward slash (/) and backslash (\) in file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428561/difference-between-forward-slash-and-backslash-in-file-path)