# Python won't find a file that actually is there

Tags: python, file, audio

I am trying to make a game where you can give it a song and it checks for the note with the highest volume in intervals eg, 5 seconds or so. This way it can place a button on the screen at that time for the player to click. I'm currently trying to wrap my head around the way some of this audio analysing stuff works and keep getting this error I am unable to fix.

My code:

```
import pyautogui
import win32api, win32con
import threading

import time
from time import sleep

import keyboard
import random

from ast import Str
import pygame
from pygame import *
import sys

import math
import numpy

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot

import pydub
from pydub import AudioSegment

song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(r"C:\Users\William Cunningham\Desktop\Stuff\Visual Studio\Games\KeyClickGame\AlienWaifus.mp3")


SEGMENT_MS = 50
volume = [segment.dBFS for segment in song[::SEGMENT_MS]]

x_axis = numpy.arrange(len(volume)) * (SEGMENT_MS / 1000)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x_axis, volume)
matplotlib.pyplot.show
```

The error I am getting:

```
C:\Users\William Cunningham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
C:\Users\William Cunningham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\William Cunningham\Desktop\Stuff\Visual Studio\Games\KeyClickGame\AudioStuff.py", line 33, in <module>
    song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file=r"C:\Users\William Cunningham\Desktop\Stuff\Visual Studio\Games\KeyClickGame\AlienWaifus.mp3")
  File "C:\Users\William Cunningham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 796, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)
  File "C:\Users\William Cunningham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
  File "C:\Users\William Cunningham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\William Cunningham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\William Cunningham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I'm quite new to coding so I don't have any idea what this means, however I believe at the last line it seems to say it cant find my file however it is clearly there.

I have attempted to change:
`song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(r"C:\Users\William Cunningham\Desktop\Stuff\Visual Studio\Games\KeyClickGame\AlienWaifus.mp3")`
to:
`song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file=r"C:\Users\William Cunningham\Desktop\Stuff\Visual Studio\Games\KeyClickGame\AlienWaifus.mp3")`

I have also tried it without the r in r". And furthermore tried it as only "AlienWaifus.mp3". I have also tried to do the same things with from_file instead of from_mp3. Adding to this I have attempted to do `SongA = open(r"C:\Users\William Cunningham\Desktop\Stuff\Visual Studio\Games\KeyClickGame\AlienWaifus.mp3")` and then do `SongB = AudioSegment.from_file(SongA)`, and also `SongB = AudioSegment.from_mp3(SongA)`.

I'm not sure what I'm doing to be completely honest though I have tried everything I could think of, and eventually decided to come here. (I'm new so my formatting on the question may not be right please let me know if this is the case!)

What I Want: I want to have code that looks at an audio file (.mp3) and for each say 10 second interval in the song (the audio file is a song) it checks at what point it is loudest. In decibels. So it say returns a time, furthermore I would like to be able to get graphs for different things and even play the song but at the moment I just want to get this working. (My code at the moment is for a graph that shows volume of the .mp3 file over time but it doesn't work and I want it to work.)
Note: I would prefer not to install any software and just be able to code this if possible.

Comment: Try changing your `\` to `/` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428561/difference-between-forward-slash-and-backslash-in-file-path

Comment: The file it can't find might not be your song.... it could be ffmpeg  you need to install ffmpeg and ffprobe

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Alexander I'm not sure what you mean by that. (Sorry I'm new to coding) could you elaborate on what that means and how I would go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Mate**. I don't really use windows but it appears you need to install `FFmpeg` in your system. I was able to find a link that might help with setting up the `Windows System Variables`

Link - [How to setup FFmpeg on Windows](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/)

Comment: Sorry it seems I've been unclear. Is there a way to fix my code so I don't have to install any software like that?

Comment: I don't a specific software for that mate but in Linux OBS always requires FFmpeg to be installed. I don't know if maybe installing OBS would install the library for you.